# Jersey Filter is giving 404 for actuator api internally

Tags: java, jersey

I extended the application, so that actuators like health are working. Within the JerseyConfig i added property(FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true); The jersey filtering is configured as follows spring.jersey.type=filter

The actuator endpoint works as expected so actuator/health returns a 200 and the expected response, but in fact jersey throws an NotFoundexception internally, which can seen in logs.

If I remove that property I get 404 for actuator endpoint.